# automation of oracle ebs using open source technology

Tags: oracle-ebs

Any open source tool that can be used for the above mention **technology**.
Can somebody give me couple of options regarding this . any help in this topic would be help be achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Download the 'Dataloader' from http://www.dataload.com/downloads/index.html